# Drop box and Reputation page displaying different totals

Tags: bug

Right now, my dropbox claims I've earned 295 reputation points; but the total listed in my reputation page is listed as 305.

Here's a screenshot (sorry, I don't have the necessary software to edit the image right now to highlight the differences, but if someone can that will be fine).

[image]

This happens sometimes. Any idea why? I assume that the correct total is the one in the reputation page.

Comment: If you want to be totally sure to go http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation and see what it says, if needed - trigger a recalc.

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, I know about recalcs, and they will likely "fix" the issue; but why do they give different totals? And of course, one can only trigger a recalc every so often...

Comment: If you have checked the "Show removed posts" it may show additional points which you have received.

Comment: @Asaf: Well, that *is* news. I didn't know about that box. But it does not show me any deleted posts on today's tally.

Comment: Hmpfs. I recall that I had the same problem a while ago and then I figured it out... Too bad my memory has an infinite genus.

Comment: @Asaf I did not know about http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation . Where is it documented?

Comment: @Mark: It's not fully documented, and now it is less needed since reputation recalcs are automatic in 99% of the time. It is just a system log of all the votes your posts have received.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the "why" is because one place (most likely the lower total) is somehow cached between the raw data and the output hitting your browser.  If the issue self-corrects within 5-10 minutes, that's most likely what's happening.

Comment: @Isaac: It persisted for well over an hour. It disappeared after I recalculated.